# Strange issue with foreach, differential arrays

Tags: php, laravel

We are trying to compare differents from two arrays, the code is working on w3schools example

```
$new=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow", "g"=>"purple");
$old=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"white","d"=>"black");

$seen = array( );
foreach ($new as $n) {
[Line 469]        $seen[strtolower($n)]++;
}

foreach ($old as $key => $o) {
    $o = strtolower($o);
    if (!$seen[$o]) { 
      $diffold[$key] = $o; 
    }
}


  $seen2 = array( );
  foreach ($old as $o) {
    $seen2[strtolower($o)]++;
}

foreach ($new as $key => $n) {
    $n = strtolower($n);
    if (!$seen2[$n]) { $diffnew[$key] = $n; }
}


  print_r($diffold);
  print_r($diffnew);

  foreach($diffold as $key => $value) {
    echo "<br>old value is: ".$key." => " . $diffold[$key] ."";
  }

  foreach($diffnew as $key => $value) {
    echo "<br>new value is: ".$key." => " . $diffnew[$key] ."";
  }
```

result is as excepted

```
Array ( [c] => white [d] => black ) Array ( [c] => blue [d] => yellow [g] => purple )
old value is: c => white
old value is: d => black
new value is: c => blue
new value is: d => yellow
new value is: g => purple
```

However we try the same with Laravel and PHP 7+ and we receive this error

```
ErrorException: Undefined index: red in file ...Controller.php on line 469
```

Any advice please why this is happening?

Thank you in advance

Comment: just a note: get off w3schools asap. It's a really bad resource for PHP, filled with bad practice and super outdated code

Comment: i see, thank you for the tip treyBake

Comment: $seen[strtolower($n)]++; i'll mark it on the content too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Your Complete Code by this. It will Work. [DEMO](https://paiza.io/projects/yH5LZJlgE-w3-a_pBwyfBQ)

```
$new=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow", "g"=>"purple");
$old=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"white","d"=>"black");

$seen = array( );
$i=1;
foreach ($new as $n) {
    $seen[strtolower($n)] = $i;
    $i++;
}

foreach ($old as $key => $o) {
    $o = strtolower($o);

    if (!isset($seen[$o])) { 
      $diffold[$key] = $o; 
    }
}

$i=1;
  $seen2 = array( );
  foreach ($old as $o) {
    $seen2[strtolower($o)] = $i;
    $i++;
}

foreach ($new as $key => $n) {
    $n = strtolower($n);
    if (!isset($seen2[$n])) { 
        $diffnew[$key] = $n; 
    }
}

print_r($diffold);
print_r($diffnew);

  foreach($diffold as $key => $value) {
    echo "<br>old value is: ".$key." => " . $diffold[$key] ."";
  }

  foreach($diffnew as $key => $value) {
    echo "<br>new value is: ".$key." => " . $diffnew[$key] ."";
  }
```

**OUTPUT Without ERROR**

```
Array
(
    [c] => white
    [d] => black
)
Array
(
    [c] => blue
    [d] => yellow
    [g] => purple
)

old value is: c => white
old value is: d => black
new value is: c => blue
new value is: d => yellow
new value is: g => purplesomething
```

Answer (score 0):

The error results from trying to increase integer numbers of an yet undefined field.

On the first iteration, the array `$seen` is empty and therefore no keys exist in it. When trying to increase the value of an entry (`$seen[ strtolower( $n ) ]++;`), you  will need to check if this entry already exists in that array:

```
foreach ($new as $n) {
    $key = strtolower($n);
    if ( ! isset($seen[$key])) {
        $seen[$key] = 1;
    } else {
        $seen[$key]++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

#### Evaluating non-exist keys in an array will get warning.

Code like

```php
if (!$seen[$o]) {
```

Should be

```php
if (!isset($seen[$o])) {
```

#### Incrementing non-exists assoc key will get warning

Code like

```php
seen[strtolower($n)]++;
```

Should be

```php
seen[strtolower($n)] = isset(seen[strtolower($n)]) ? seen[strtolower($n)]+1 : 1;
```